# How to run a cloned Laravel project with sail on Windows?

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, composer-php, laravel-sail

I cloned an existing Laravel project from git which was dockerized with Sail. As vendor is in the .gitignore, I need to rebuild it before I can use Sail to run my app. Acording to the Laravel doc (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects) i need to get my dependencies using this command.

```
docker run --rm \
-u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
-v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
-w /var/www/html \
laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Problem is both cmd and powershell seem to struggle with the $'s, it seams that they expect an applet name, and I can't manage to run this. What am I missing ?

The error I am getting with PS is

> id : The term "id" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.

In cmd, i got

> docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.

I also tried with git bash and got

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

Comment: Please, share the error you are getting

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: So, not recognizing `id` command, I have no idea, but it is saying it has no idea what `id` is. If you run `id -u` in your terminal, does it work?

Comment: git bash outputs 6-digit numbers when i run `id -u` and `id -g`, the two others fail

Comment: I am so confused, `pwd` is going to share the path you are in, and it works on Mac and Linux

Comment: I guess that it's a command provided for unix based environments, which is why git bash seems to understand it better than the two others. I wish I had a translation for powershell or cmd

Comment: I am sorry, I thought you were using Mac I do not know why. I recommend you to use WSL

Answer (score 2):

Only execute the command in the WSL2 Distribution (as example, Ubuntu)

First, Open the wsl console from PowerShell pointing the project folder

```
wsl -d ubuntu
```

And then execute the docker command for execute Laravel sail

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

I recommend check your php version for available laravel sail compatibility

> When using the laravelsail/phpXX-composer image, you should use the same version of PHP that you plan to use for your application (74, 80, or 81).

Font: [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects)

Comment: yes, i have already tried that and it works well too. But one of the advantage of docker is that it should run the same in every OS.  And here i had to install WSL to install dependencies first in my windows OS.